# Most efficient way to share private code samples to potential employers on GitHub?

Tags: github

I have currently a public GitHub account with lots of my older code on it but I want to share some of my newer, but private code with employers that I am applying to because it's more relevant. This code is my own, copyrighted code. I don't want to release it as open source software or make it publicly accessible since I'm using this code in apps currently on the app store.

The question I have is this: How do you share it with potential employers on GitHub? That they obviously need to have a GitHub account is clear but do they need to be in your team or is there any other way to let them see the code (preferably read-only)?

Sure, I could just mail in my code or zip it up and share it password-protected on my server but I'd prefer to make it as easy as possible to check the code for employers, without many obstacles in the way.

Answer (score 3):

Your question mentions "code samples" and a "read-only" way to share the code.

What about uploading only the most relevant excerpts of your code? You could even use Gists:

> Gists are a great way to share your work. You can share single files, parts of files, or full applications. You can access gists at https://gist.github.com.
>
> ...
>
> Secret gists don't show up in Discover and are not searchable. Use them to jot down an idea that came to you in a dream, create a to-do list, or prepare some code or prose that's not ready to be shared with the world.
>
> ...
>
> Warning: Secret gists aren't private. If you send the URL of a secret gist to a friend, they'll be able to see it. However, if someone you don't know discovers the URL, they'll also be able to see your gist.

[About Gists](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/)